# SQL Stored Procedure: Poor performance until text is changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

We have run into a strange issue recently. We have a lot of stored procedures on a SQL Azure database and it appears that a number of them keep choosing poor plans to execute the query. We are updating stats on the databases nightly. When we see a stored procedure timing out over and over we tried executing sp_recompile passing in the procedure name and it does get recompiled but doesn't solve the bad plan problem.  We tried actually rerunning the ALTER PROCEDURE statement (without changing the actual contents of the procedure) and that did nothing. Then on a whim we change the text of the procedure by adding a newline at the end of it right before the END statement. When we do this and run the ALTER PROCEDURE statement, the procedure suddenly kicks into gear and runs fast again.

I assume alerting the text of the procedure "changes" the procedure more than sp_recompile does and forces a "harder" recompilation and thus a better query plan is chosen?  The problem is, while this solves the issue, there is now way to maintain a system of over 100 production databases where this seems to randomly happen.  Has anyone else seen this type off issue and know what the underlying problem may be? How does one maintain a system like this?

Comment: Would `OPTION RECOMPILE` work for what you are doing?  If the stored procedures are doing "batches", then then the recompiling is probably a small amount of effort compared to the overall work being done.

Comment: We have tried adding that on some of the stored procedures but it always feels like a hack. Feels like there is an underlying problem that we aren't solving for.  But, a good suggestion to see if that does solve it.

Comment: When ALTER PROCEDURE doesn't work, do DROP and CREATE? FYI, SQL execution plans are compiled and cached separately for each set of @@OPTIONS values. Sounds like your application connects to the SQL instance with a different set of @@OPTIONS than what you do when using SSMS/AzDS, so you'll see different performance characteristics from SSMS/AzDS. Try adding "option (recompile)" to the end of particular SQL statements inside the stored procedures, but that throws plan caching out with the baby's bath water and will cause some compilation time to be added to each query invocation.

Comment: Also, your particular issue of "the procedure suddenly kicks into gear and runs fast again" sounds like a flavour of plan caching issues related to "Parameter Sniffing". This can be particularly troublesome for multi-tenant databases where the tables are indexed with a BusinessID/OrganizationID/UnitID style of index key and the shape of data for given customers can vary wildly within a particular table. (Histograms for statistics only have 200 buckets on older versions of SQL Server.)

Comment: @NickOlsen . . . To be honest, when I was faced with changing execution plans on views (as opposed to stored procedures), I simply forced the joins to use the right join type using options.  That way, I could sleep more soundly at night.